# Browser.newPage() not opening a new tab. Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am facing an issue here that I can't seem to understand. I am using Puppeteer on nodejs for web scraping. I have followed the same procedure as specified in the documentation. And the browser opens and works for the first time. But once it closes. The next time it does not open a new tab and is just stuck after opening the browser.

After closing it gets stuck her..[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIMM9.png)

Here is the code that I am using for this:

```
const browser = await pupeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page
    .goto(
      "https://www.dsmz.de/collection/catalogue/microorganisms/catalogue"
    )
    .then(() => {
      page.type("#search_term", "to");
    });
await browser.close();
```

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "next time". Do you have a loop of some sort?

Comment: No. I am requesting the server by postman.

Comment: Voting to close as  missing a [mcve]. If you're "requesting the server by postman", please show your server route that's ostensibly launching the browser. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with this code other than the antipattern of mixing `.then` and `await` unnecessarily.